# Given a family of schemes $\pi:X \to B$ which is generically smooth how can I find the singular locus $B_{sing}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Consider the weierstrauss family of elliptic curves
$$
\text{Spec}\left( \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,\lambda]}{(y^2 - x(x-1)(x-\lambda))} \right) \to \mathbb{A}^1_\lambda
$$
the singular locus is $\{0,1\}$. In general, if I have a morphism of schemes
$$
X \to B
$$
that is generically smooth, how can I compute the singular locus $B_{sing}$?

Comment: @Ravi I wrote that into my question

Comment: I think the example has the germ of the general idea: Break up your (possibly non affine) schemes into affine schemes and check everything locally.

Comment: Oh, I think this is pages 230-239 of "Geometry of Schemes" by Eisenbud, Harris

Comment: I need to read this and try out the family of quintic 3-folds $x_0^5 + \cdots + x_4^5 - \psi x_0x_1x_2x_3x_4$